# Learning to debug in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, stack-trace

Does anybody know a good place to learn how to use the debugger in Xcode?  I'm hoping to understand how to use things like stack trace, the debug log, and anything else I don't really know about.  Online tutorials would be best, but I'm not opposed to buying a book either.  Thank you.

Comment: The log is easy.  If it's in bold text and in comprehensible human-readable English: it's pretty darn important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the Xcode documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html) about debugging and you will know all the basics.

Answer (score 2):

There was a session at WWDC 2011 called [*Effective Debugging with Xcode*](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.8266478284.08266478290.8365294561?i=1092444596). The link is to the video in iTunes, so you should be able to watch it.

Learning to debug is really two skills: learning how to use the tools, and learning what to do with them. It shouldn't take you long to get the basics -- setting a breakpoint, inspecting values, etc. Really getting good takes much longer.